# Nested for Loop In Directory

Tags: shell-script

I have two sets of files organized as such:

```
#first directory
/direc1/files

file0.1.tar.gz
file0.2.tar.gz
file0.3.tar.gz
file0.4.tar.gz
      .
      .
      .
file0.22.tar.gz
```

In this directory, I have 242 files in total. 
My current nested command to run script.py is below:

```
for z in `seq 0 10`; do
for i in `seq 1 22`; do python script.py --l2 --ld-wind-cm 1 --annot  file${z}.${i} --thin-annot --out  file${z}.${i} --print-snps;done;done
```

If you notice, I have hardcoded `file` in this loop. Is there a way to run this without using `file${z}.${i}` and instead using a variable?

Comment: This stopped being the same question when you brought a second directory into it. Having it there pretty much invalidates the existing answers. Please, write your questions so that they include all the necessary detail.

Comment: Ok, I'll make a new question instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request is not quite clear. Why the two loops across the two ranges? Wouldn't

```
for FN in *.tar.gz; do echo python script.py --out "$FN"; done
```

be sufficient? Remove the `echo` if happy with the result.

If there is NO other file than the ones you want to work upon, the "extensions" can go away as well, run the `for` loop across `*`.

Comment: Hi, I have clarified my question, if that is ok?

Answer (score 3):

If there are other tar.gz files there besides those files you need you can use:

```
for i in file{0..10}.{1..22}.tar.gz; do python script.py --out "$i" --print-file; done
```

If these are the only files in the folder then this is sufficient, and will work with any file name.

```
for i in * ; do python script.py --out "$i" --print-file; done
```

If these are the only tar.gz files in folder, but there are some other type of files there then this can be used and can work with any name of tar.gz files:

```
for i in *.tar.gz ; do python script.py --out "$i" --print-file; done
```